# C# How to use Statements in strings to parse text

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I've been working on a text based game for a while now, and one of the issues I have run into is when I have to write paragraphs that are different based on variables that can change throughout the game.

I've looked around for parsers and such but mostly found regex, which I don't think is useful here. What I am looking for is some way to look at a string like this.

`String x = "'It's nice to meet you [if (Female){ "Miss, what's a pretty young thing like you doing out in the dessert."} else { "Sir, what can I do for ya?"}]' the man asks in a drawl.";`

I currently have to write the paragraphs broken up with if statements, but it takes a lot longer to write and makes it harder to keep the conversation flow in my head. And my goal is to have a class I could sent the string to and get back a formatted version at execute time based on variables that change throughout the game.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is your goal, c# really isn't the tool for you. It simply doesn't offer this feature, and while it [will offer string interpolation in version 6.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/846566/What-s-new-in-Csharp-String-Interpolation), I doubt it will ever support full-statements like you want. This sort of feature is simply not a goal of the language and would actually make one of the primary goals (first-rate tool support) far more difficult.

An interesting alternative might be to write the code that does the interpolation in powershell which is dynamic, [supports full string interpolation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx), is installed on every Windows machine since Windows XP 3, and interoperates natively with any .Net language.

You could even do this by having the rest of your code in c# by [calling powershell for just that one component](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx).

Since powershell syntax for ifs looks very similar to c# your code might look something like

```
interpolate(@"'It's nice to meet you $(if (Female){ ""Miss, what's a pretty 
young thing like you doing out in the dessert.""} else { ""Sir, what can I 
do for ya?""})' the man asks in a drawl.");
```

That being said, its not super simple to do this but might be your best alternative if string-interpolation from c# code files is a must-have.

Other alternatives:

- Same thing but use any other .Net language that supports interpolation rather than Powershell
- Write your strings as Razor templates and use [RazorEngine](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/4.0.0-beta2) to compile them
- Use features from the upcoming Roslyn compiler to compile your strings as c#.

None of this stuff is easier, but its all doable.

Comment: George, actually the 6.0 feature looks like exactly what I want. I'm going to take a look at it, but thanks very much for the reply. I use PowerShell a lot for work, but didn't think to take advantage of it for this personal project but I will now.

Comment: Worst advice I have ever seen -- each language itself covers a little of features, and if you have something extra you write class/function/library. Missing feature like this is not the reason for switching entire language.

Comment: Nor did I write that he should switch @greenoldman. I didn't mention that powershell interoperates natively with c# and link to an article on how to call a ps component from powershell for funsies. The op asked how to do something in c# that is not possible, I pointed him to how to do the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you want, but here is one approach. Have a class which generates responses for each conversation based on the gender:

```
class CharacterResponses
{
    private bool _isFemale;

    new CharacterResponses(bool isFemale)
    {
        _isFemale = isFemale;
    }

    public string GetResponse1()
    {
        return _isFemale
            ? "Miss, what's a pretty young thing like you doing out in the dessert."
            : "Sir, what can I do for ya?";
    }

    public string GetResponse2() // For a different conversation.
    // etc...
}
```

Now in your program, you could have a flow like this:

```
var character = new CharacterResponses(true); // Female.
var x = string.Format("It's nice to meet you {0} the man asks in a drawl.", character.GetResponse1());
```

This keeps all the `if` - `then` logic specific to the character's gender in its own code block and allows you to easily put placeholders in the main conversation.

Comment: Nice one, only problem here would be that you have to make a new method for each conversation. you could fix this by adding 2 string parameters to the GetResponse method, one is the value for true, the second is the value for false. just a suggestion.

Comment: @JoJo - Certainly. If a response is dependent on other factors (outside of gender), that could be passed into a specific `GetResponse` method as parameters.

Comment: An even better approach might be to have `Female` and `Male` be classes that conform to an interface, and have each provide its own implementation of `string DesertSalutation()` for example

Comment: Sadly every conversation could be different, I think at this point I have thirty different scenes that have an average of five different variable options each.

Comment: @Eric.E check my other comment (first one in the list), there's something that might help using this solution

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of text, and a lot of possible variations, I would suggest you write up some code that generates the strings for you. And it doesn't seem very nice to have them mixed up in the source code anyway (imho).

How about some xml?

```
<Message Key="message123">
    <Text>It's nice to meet you </Text>
    <Switch Field="Gender">
        <Female>
            Miss, what's a pretty young thing like you
            doing out in the dessert?
        </Female>
        <Male>Sir, what can I do for ya?</Male>
    </Switch>
    <Text> the man asks in a drawl</Text>
</Message>
```

Throw in some code for `<If>` statements and other stuff and you'll have a lot of flexibility. I.e. different text based on other variables, such as health or inventory items.

Not really an answer to your question, but figured I'd add my two cents anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Write the class `StringInterpolated` (name does not really matters) which interpolates strings (in your format). The only downside is that you would have to attach argument at the end -- in your example `Female`.

Depending on your needs you could throw any syntax to interpolate the string you want, you could also add a check if all arguments with values are passed, so this side would be covered.